# How would I omit zero value decimals in a number format?

Tags: number

Say I have `{{ item.width }}` and `{{ item.height }}` which are number fields with 2 decimal places.

In my template I have this:

```
<p>Dimensions: {{ item.width }} x {{ item.height }} in.</p>
```

Which will output like this:

> Dimensions: 8.50 x 11.00 in.
>
> Dimensions: 5.00 x 7.00 in.
>
> Dimensions: 4.25 x 6.50 in.

How would I drop the decimal places that are not used?  Like this:

> Dimensions: 8.5 x 11 in.
>
> Dimensions: 5  x 7 in.
>
> Dimensions: 4.25 x 6.5 in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For all those looking for a zeroes-trimming **solution for just a single decimal place**, please consider the following:

```
{{ item.width | replace({".0" : ""}) }}
```

In our case, the [previously posted solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/568/37) will not work reliably, because…

> {{ item.width|trim('0')|trim('.') }}

…will correctly trim down `3.0` to `3`, but transform `0.3` to `3` just the same. `replace()`, instead, does work like a charm.

Comment: I just updated the other answer... It simply needed `'right'` specified for each trim.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done with Twig's `trim` filter. It works just like PHP's trim function.

```
{{ item.width|trim('0','right')|trim('.','right') }}
```

Comment: Dammit, you're too fast. I had the link to [trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html) ready and everything. Wouldn't `trim('0')` suffice?

Comment: That does not really work, if I have an entry with '10' in the number field it will output 10.00 but when I add the trim it outputs '1'.  I don't think I can trust the client to always enter it as '10.00' and not '10'

Comment: @pixelJitsu Which doesn't work? `trim('.0')`, `trim('0')`, or both? This should totally be an output thing, no way you should have your clients remember to enter numbers a certain way!

Comment: trim('.0') = 8.5 x 1 & trim('0') = 8. x 11.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. Then we do it in phases. Answer Updated.

Answer (score 9):

multiply by 1:

`{{ 12.50 * 1 }} == 12.5`

`{{ 12.0 * 1 }} == 12`

Comment: By far the best way to do it

Answer (score 5):

I would use the twig [number_format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) filter to make sure there were a known number of decimal places, then [trim](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html) first the 0s, then the '.':

```
{{item.width|number_format(4)|trim('0')|trim('.')}}
```

I would write a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) for this:

```
{% macro num_format(n) %}
  {{n|number_format(4)|trim('0')|trim('.')}}
{% endmacro %}
```

Called like so:

```
{{ num_format(item.width) }}
```

Comment: The {{item.width|number_format(4)|trim('0')|trim('.')}} is a good approach if you're handling JUST integers...

Answer (score 3):

This limits it to 4 places and trims only trailing zeroes.

`{{ item.width | number_format(4) | trim("0", "right") | trim(".") }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a filter to twig ([adding filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters))

And make it sound like this:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('roundIf', function ($val) {
    return number_format($val, (int)$val == $val ? 0 : 2, ',', ' ');
});
```

Then use it in your code like

```
{{ item.width | roundIf }} {{ item.height | roudIf }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pipe that much, you should be able to use `sprintf` and do something like this:

`{{ '%02g' | format(item.width) }}`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format.html

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 1):

```
{% set test1 = "12.05" %}
{% set test1 = test1 // 1 %}
```

The output will be 12