# Price Formatting

Tags: format, number

I'm outputting prices in a channel with a little formatting like so:

```
&pound;{{ entry.priceFrom|number_format(2,'.',',') }}
```

Gives me £1,000.00 or £99.99 etc... However client isn't a fan of the double zeros (e.g. £100.00) and would prefer such prices to show up as £100 – only showing decimal numbers if they're not "00".

I was working on some kind of preprocessing/condition here but it seems long-winded, and wondered if anyone has a neat solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Craft comes with a [currency](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#currency) filter that makes this pretty easy – you don’t even need the `&pound;`:

```
{{ entry.priceFrom|currency('GBP', true) }}
```

The `'GBP'` establishes the currency (so the price is prefixed with `£`), and passing `true` to the second argument tells Craft to strip out the cents from the formatted string if there aren’t any (so `£100` instead of `£100.00`).

Comment: Wow, great thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
&pound;{{ 1000.00 | number_format(2,'.',',') | replace({".00" : ""}) }}
```

gives:

£1,000

Got a similar idea from [How would I omit zero value decimals in a number format?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/566/how-would-i-omit-zero-value-decimals-in-a-number-format).

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference, Craft 3 is a little different with the currency filter.

```
{{ entry.price|currency('CAD', stripZeros = true) }}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what makes your answer different than Brandons?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I tried using this one ('CAD', true) in my new Craft 3 build and was getting an error. So you have to use this ('CAD', stripZeros = true) for it to work in Craft 3

Answer (score 1):

Well I've got this working with:

```
{% set decimal = entry.priceFrom|reverse|slice(1,2) %}

{% if decimal == "0" %}{{ entry.priceFrom|number_format(0,'.',',') }}{% else %}{{ entry.priceFrom|number_format(2,'.',',') }}{% endif %}
```

Basically I'm reversing the string so I can check for a zero at the end (or not). It's fairly clean, but if anyone can improve on it I'd love to hear.